# char8 & uchar8 Equivalent

Tags: c#

I am working on a program, or I communicate with a card via UDP, the answers of the card I recover them in a Byte table and I put them in an int32 but they ask me that the gain be coded in uchar8 and Pedestal in char8, what is it the equivalent of char8 and uchar8 in C # and what exactly is 0.255 the max and min value?

[char8 & uchar8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZENl.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

As far as the specification you're asking about goes, you'll need to ask the author of the specification for specifics. However, based solely on the image you've provided, I'd say that yes, the numerical values given indicate the minimum and maximum values allowed for the types. As such, the equivalent C# types would be `sbyte` for your `char8` type, and `byte` for the `uchar8` type.

The former has a range of `-128` to `127` (it's a signed type), while the latter has a range of `0` to `255` (being an unsigned type). Both are stored as single bytes, and as such have 256 different possible values.